# Fetching table td's count from jquery post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, count

I'm trying to fetch how many number of records I get inside my table. I've tried to fetch the row count like following (number of records):

```
       var length = $(data).find('#tableProducts').get(0).children('tr').children('td').length
console.log($(data).find('#tableProducts'));
```

The method above returns me 0 value every time.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so did it :

```
$(data).find('#tableProducts')[0].childNodes[3].childElementCount
```

Answer (score 0):

`.get(0)` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so you can't use a jQuery method like `.children()` on it.

You don't need to do that at all, just call `.children()` on the result of the selector.

```
var length = $(data).find('#tableProducts').children('tr').children('td').length;
```